# Why does my express wildcard route override my static middleware?

Tags: node.js, express

I've been having an issue with Express v.4.14.  My wildcard route seems to be overriding my static middleware.  Here is the code:

```
    const app = express()
    const indexPath = path.join(__dirname, './index.html')
    const publicPath = express.static(path.join(__dirname, './public'))

    app.use('/public', publicPath)
    app.get('/*', function(req, res) { res.sendFile(indexPath); });

    return app
```

For some reason, a request to '/public/SomeExistingFile.js' returns '/index.html'.  If I remove the wildcard (*) then the static middleware is not overridden, but I no longer match arbitrary routes.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

*Extra Context:  I am trying to use Webpack to serve a single page web app with React, React Router and Redux.*

Comment: Adding `app.use('/public', publicPath)` after route definition may help.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  Unfortunately I am getting the same issue:  All requests are directed to "/index.html" including requests to "/public/SomeExistingFile.js"

Comment: i tried something similar and worked for me, maybe some code you have not included in the post is causing the problem.

Answer (score -2):

You are using /* which will route all the routes to that route only. So you can add some path before /* like mypath/* so that it will not override your static path

Comment: I was under the impression that the static middleware would catch routes going to "/public/*".  This is the case when I do not use the wildcard route, but I was intending to keep the wildcard route to catch all routes which do not route to "/public/*"